# .NET Web Service Using WEB CONFIG Settings Hard Coded Net TCP

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, tcp

I wanted to confirm something.

Below is how I am spinning up a call to my WCF web service in my ASP.NET application.

```
var xml = "my xml string";
var ep = new EndpointAddress("http://myendpoint");
xml = new Proxy.ServiceClient(new NetTcpBinding(), ep).getNewXML(new Proxy.CallContext(), xml);
```

My web config looks similar to below. My question is, even though these settings are in the web config, the fact that my calls above are newing up the a service client and fresh New TCP binding everytime tell me that these settings aren't being referenced. Is this correct based on above?

```
 <system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
   <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NetTcpBinding_SCSService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
     openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
     transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
     hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
     maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
     <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
      maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
     <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
      enabled="false" />
     <security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
      <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
     </security>
    </binding>
   </netTcpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
   <endpoint address="net.tcp://myendpoint"
    binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_SCSService"
    contract="Proxy.Service" name="NetTcpBinding_SCSService">
    <identity>
     <userPrincipalName value="user@user.com" />
    </identity>
   </endpoint>
  </client>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: With this style of constructing a service client you will not have the usual WCF client caching. This can be a major performance problem.

Comment: Simple enough, just comment out the configuration and try to run your app.. if it blows up, you know your answer.

Comment: @usr: Wonderful point. The MRU `ChannelFactory` cache introduced in .NET 3.0 SP1 does not kick in when you supply a binding or access any of the public properties of the Proxy. The `ChannelFactory` is the expensive bit, especially if there any sort of security negotiation involved up front. I bet if the OP just maintained a static reference to his proxy throughout the lifetime of the application - he could potentially see a boost in performance.

Comment: If the OP is interested in the subject of Proxy/ ChannelFactory caching to improve the performance of his application. These two articles are quite helpful: [WCF Proxies: To Cache or Not to Cache?](http://devproconnections.com/net-framework/wcf-proxies-cache-or-not-cache) and [Performance Improvement for WCF Client Proxy Creation in .NET 3.5 and Best Practices](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2007/10/27/performance-improvement-of-wcf-client-proxy-creation-and-best-practices.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. In this case, you are not using the configuration settings found in the config file.

Proxies typically derive from the abstract class [`ClientBase<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576141(v=vs.110).aspx) which provides several different ways to create an instance of a client proxy. Some of the constructors listed will use all of the config file while others will attempt to use the config file to fill in the information that has not been explicitly supplied in the constructor. There are even constructor overloads which do not use the configuration file at all which `ClientBase<TChannel>(Binding, EndpointAddress)` is one of them.

If you wanted to use what was in the application configuration file, you could use:

```
var client = new Proxy.ServiceClient("NetTcpBinding_SCSService");
```